# TypeError: EthereumTransaction is not a constructor

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

```
var EthereumTransaction = require("ethereumjs-tx")

var Web3 = require('web3')

var web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')

//Setting Receiving and Sending Address

var sendingAddress = acc1

var receivingAddress = acc2

//Checking the balance of each account in ether

web3.eth.getBalance(sendingAddress).then(console.log(web3.utils.fromWei('1', 'ether')))

web3.eth.getBalance(receivingAddress).then(console.log(web3.utils.fromWei('1', 'ether')))

//Creating a transaction

var rawTransaction ={
    nounce:0,
    to:receivingAddress,
    gasPrice:20000000,
    gasLimit:30000,
    value:100,
    data:""
}

//Sign the Transaction

var privateKey = 'private key goes here'

var senderPrivateKeyHex = new Buffer(privateKey,'hex')

var transaction = new EthereumTransaction(rawTransaction)

transaction.sign(senderPrivateKeyHex)

//Send transaction to the network

var serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize()

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTransaction)
```

Error Occurred is.

```
TypeError: EthereumTransaction is not a constructor
```

Comment: Type `npm ls ethereumjs-tx` in a console and tell us what you're getting.

Comment: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.21.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
simpleTransaction@1.0.0 /mnt/d/Blockchain/BlockchainTest/SimpleTransaction
├── ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2
└─┬ web3@1.2.9
  └─┬ web3-eth@1.2.9
    └─┬ web3-eth-accounts@1.2.9
      └── ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2  deduped

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because `ethereumjs-tx` library has changed its [syntax](https://openbase.com/js/ethereumjs-tx/documentation).

This is the working version of your code:

```js
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

var Web3 = require('web3')

var web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')

//Setting Receiving and Sending Address

var sendingAddress = 'ADD SENDING ADDRESS HERE'

var receivingAddress = 'ADD RECEIVING ADDRESS HERE'

//Checking the balance of each account in ether

web3.eth.getBalance(sendingAddress).then(console.log(web3.utils.fromWei('1', 'ether')))

web3.eth.getBalance(receivingAddress).then(console.log(web3.utils.fromWei('1', 'ether')))

//Creating a transaction

var rawTransaction ={
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(0),
    to: receivingAddress,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(20000000),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(30000),
    value: web3.utils.toHex(100),
    data: web3.utils.toHex("")
}

//Sign the Transaction

var privateKey = 'private key goes here'

var senderPrivateKeyHex = new Buffer.from(privateKey,'hex')

var transaction = new EthereumTx(rawTransaction)

transaction.sign(senderPrivateKeyHex)

//Send transaction to the network

var serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize()

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTransaction)
```

Comment: This works, perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   var transaction = new TX(rawTransaction);
```

instead of this

```
  var transaction = new EthereumTransaction(rawTransaction)
```

Comment: No it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`var TX = require('ethereumjs-tx')`.Transaction will remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using version `2.1.2` of the `ethereumjs-tx` library, but you want to use an earlier version.

If you install version `1.3.7` you should be alright. Try running this from the command line and see if your error goes away.

```
npm install ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7 --save
```

For version 2 and onwards the syntax to initialize the library has changed to `require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction`. You can see an example [here](https://openbase.io/js/ethereumjs-tx/documentation)